# Optimize laravel query many-to-many cascade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, optimization

I'm trying to optimize my query because it takes far, far too long to execute.

My model consists of 6 tables, see ER diagram:

[ER Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU3UT.png)

This is my Query builder:

```
 $events =  Event::orderBy('date','DESC')->with(['person', 'person.country', 'person.topics', 'train', 'station'])->get();
```

I have also already indexed the different tables.

Between topic and person there is a pivot table:

```
public function topics()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Topic::class, 'person_topic')->withPivot('quantity')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

when you are using eager loading in your models it will translate your eloquent query to many WhereIn queries so for example the below code

```
$books = Book::with('author')->get();

foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->author->name;
}
```

will be translated to these two queries:

```
select * from books

select * from authors where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

so based on your query if you want to fetch all the entities you have with all the relations I could suggest you use some join queries instead of using Laravel eager loading.

sample  from laravel docs :

```
DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.id', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

based on  **matiaslauriti** comment you can also do some paginate on your query so it fetches from database chunk by chunk.

sample  :

```
Flight::chunk(200, function ($flights) {
    foreach ($flights as $flight) {
        //
    }
});
```

there is also a `Lazy` method that does the same jobs too.

Comment: I recommend the author not to do a raw query, but change `->get()` to `paginate` or use `take` to limit the amount of models... that is the real problem, he is getting a lot of models

Comment: so my assumption was he really needs to fetch all the models. but yes, if his problem is lack of memory he should use some paginate or chunk method. i will add this part to my answer too, thanks.

Comment: Even if he needs to fetch all models, Laravel get's really slow (PHP) when it needs to fetch and load in memory like 500 to 1k and he is not limiting anything, so that is surely the problem. I say this because I had to work with reports and handling those models was a pain in the you know where, the solution was to chunk.